# Adding rounded corners to UIView disables touchesBegan

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I added bottom rounded corners to my UIView this way:

```
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.BottomLeft, .BottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(20, 20)).CGPath
self.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

Here's how it was before:[image]

After:[image]

There are 2 problems. First image at the bottom disappeared and second is that `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, etc. are not called.

Image has 3 constraints:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another method of rounding corners (which has never lead to these problems for me) is to apply these 2 methods to your view:

```
myView.clipsToBounds = true
myView.layer.cornerRadius = 5 (play with this to get what you want!)
```

Comment: I will get all corners rounded, I need only bottom

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in an `override` of `layoutSubviews` so that it uses the updated bounds:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.BottomLeft, .BottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(20, 20)).CGPath
    self.layer.mask = maskLayer
}
```

Comment: `touchesMoved`, `touchesBegan` are being called, but bottom image did not appear

Comment: Did you only put this code in `layoutSubviews()` or is it somewhere else also?

Comment: Only in `layoutSubviews()`

Comment: How is the image added to the view?  What constraints does it have for its placement?

Comment: Added in interface builder, has 3 constraints(see updated question)

Comment: So, if you comment out `layoutSubviews` the image appears?  And when you put it back the image is gone?  Does the view appear to be the same height in both cases with the only difference being the rounded corners?

Comment: Yes it appears when I comment out `layoutSubviews`. View is the same height. And I noticed if I move it up and adjust constraints it appears. If move it down, disappears

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94489/discussion-between-vacawama-and-nikita-zernov).

Comment: I'm curious, did you guys ever figure out the answer?

Comment: The above code works for me.  Nikita is doing something different and we haven't figured that out yet.